# How to implement thread-safe HashMap lazy initialization when getting value in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, java.util.concurrent, concurrenthashmap

I want to implement a util getting an Enum object by its string value. Here is my implementation.

IStringEnum.java

```
public interface IStringEnum {
    String getValue();
}
```

StringEnumUtil.java

```
public class StringEnumUtil {
    private volatile static Map<String, Map<String, Enum>> stringEnumMap = new HashMap<>();

    private StringEnumUtil() {}

    public static <T extends Enum<T>> Enum fromString(Class<T> enumClass, String symbol) {
        final String enumClassName = enumClass.getName();
        if (!stringEnumMap.containsKey(enumClassName)) {
            synchronized (enumClass) {
                if (!stringEnumMap.containsKey(enumClassName)) {
                    System.out.println("aaa:" + stringEnumMap.get(enumClassName));
                    Map<String, Enum> innerMap = new HashMap<>();
                    EnumSet<T> set = EnumSet.allOf(enumClass);
                    for (Enum e: set) {
                        if (e instanceof IStringEnum) {
                            innerMap.put(((IStringEnum) e).getValue(), e);
                        }
                    }
                    stringEnumMap.put(enumClassName, innerMap);
                }
            }
        }
        return stringEnumMap.get(enumClassName).get(symbol);
    }
}
```

I wrote a unit test in order to test whether it works in multi-thread case.

StringEnumUtilTest.java

```
public class StringEnumUtilTest {
    enum TestEnum implements IStringEnum {
        ONE("one");
        TestEnum(String value) {
            this.value = value;
        }
        @Override
        public String getValue() {
            return this.value;
        }
        private String value;
    }

    @Test
    public void testFromStringMultiThreadShouldOk() {
        final int numThread = 100;
        CountDownLatch startLatch = new CountDownLatch(1);
        CountDownLatch doneLatch = new CountDownLatch(numThread);
        List<Boolean> resultList = new LinkedList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < numThread; ++i) {
            new Thread(() -> {
                try {
                    startLatch.await();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                resultList.add(StringEnumUtil.fromString(TestEnum.class, "one") != null);
                doneLatch.countDown();
            }).start();
        }
        startLatch.countDown();
        try {
            doneLatch.await();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        assertEquals(numThread, resultList.stream().filter(item -> item.booleanValue()).count());
    }
}
```

The testing result is:

```
aaa:null

java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expected :100
Actual   :98
```

It denotes that only one thread execute this line of code:

```
System.out.println("aaa:" + stringEnumMap.get(enumClassName));
```

So the initialization codes should be executed by only one thread.

The strange thing is, the result of some thread will be `null` after executing this line of code:

```
return stringEnumMap.get(enumClassName).get(symbol);
```

Since there is no NullPointerException, `stringEnumMap.get(enumClassName)` must return the reference of `innerMap`. But why it will get `null` after calling `get(symbol)` of `innerMap`?

Please help, it drive me crazy the whole day!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is due to the line

`List<Boolean> resultList = new LinkedList<>();`

From [JavaDoc of LinkedList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html):

> **Note that this implementation is not synchronized.**If multiple threads access a linked list concurrently, and at least one of the threads modifies the list structurally, it must be synchronized externally. (A structural modification is any operation that adds or deletes one or more elements; merely setting the value of an element is not a structural modification.) This is typically accomplished by synchronizing on some object that naturally encapsulates the list.If no such object exists, the list should be "wrapped" using the Collections.synchronizedListmethod. This is best done at creation time, to prevent accidental unsynchronized access to the list:
> `List list = Collections.synchronizedList(new LinkedList(...));`

As `LinkedList` is not thread safe, and unexpected behavior may happens during the `add` operation.
Which cause the `resultList` size less than the thread count, and hence the expected count is less than the result count.
To get correct result, add `Collections.synchronizedList` as suggested.

Although you implementation is fine, I suggest you to follow Matt Timmermans answer for simpler and robust solution.

Answer (score 2):

`stringEnumMap` should be a `ConcurrentHashMap<String, Map<String,Enum>>`, and use `computeIfAbsent` to do the lazy initialization.

Answer (score 1):

## `ConcurrentMap` interface

As others noted, if manipulating a `Map` across threads you must account for concurrency.

You could handle concurrent access yourself. But there is no need. Java comes with two implementations of `Map` that are built to internally handle concurrency. These implementations implement the `ConcurrentMap` interface.

- `ConcurrentSkipListMap`
- `ConcurrentHashMap`

The first maintains the keys in sorted order, implementing the `NavigableMap` interface.

Here is a table I authored to show the characteristics of all the implementations of `Map` bundled with Java 11.

[image: Table of map implementations in Java 11, comparing their features]

You might find other third-party implementations of the `ConcurrentMap` interface.

Answer (score 0):

try moving 
 
if (!stringEnumMap.containsKey(enumClassName)) 
and the  
return stringEnumMap.get(enumClassName).get(symbol);  
into the synchronized block.